# I need to load and unload a dll once I'm done parsing a file

Tags: c#, dll, shared-libraries, .net-assembly

I have a central parsing Engine that dynamically builds the name of the DLL it wants to load (objpath) and calls the following code. I have a series of parsers (various file types and various versions) each one located in a separate dll.

My problem is that I need to unload the engine dll once the returned variable is populated. I have done a little research but have not been fruitful in finding. The Code is from the parsing Engine. objpath is the name and path of the dll needed to parse the file in question

var engine = Assembly.LoadFile(objpath);
var instance = engine.CreateInstance(obj.TypeName + ".Engine", true, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, null, null, null);
var fileImport = (IFileImport) instance;
returned = fileImport.Import(filename);

I need to unload these when not in use because I do updates and add new parsers often and currently once a parser is used its held open and there for can not be overwritten

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to load the assembly using an `AssemblyLoadContext`.

Once you're through with your assembly, you can call `Unload` on your `AssemblyLoadContext`.  You'll have to be sure that no types from your assembly are still in use, or you'll get an `InvalidOperationException`.